# How to check for authorization of two users in Laravel blade @can tag

Tags: laravel, parameters

I have 6 types of users in my application. For one view, I want to check if any one of the given two types of users are logged in. If they are, then show this item.

This is working

```
@can('admin-controller')
    <div class="custom-submit-button-group">
        <a href="/contact/viewall">View All Messages</a>
    </div>
@endcan
```

But, I want this to work. I want to show the div to these two user types.

```
@can('admin-controller' || 'general-controller')
    <div class="custom-submit-button-group">
        <a href="/contact/viewall">View All Messages</a>
    </div>
@endcan
```

But none of them can see this item.

I can use Auth::check() but I only wanted to use @can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`@canany`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/24137).

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>...</th>
    @canany(['edit_post', 'delete_post'])
    <th>Actions</th>
    @endcanany
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    @canany(['edit_post', 'delete_post'])
    <td>
      @can('edit_post')
      <button>Edit</button>
      @endcan
      @can('delete_post')
      <button>Delete</button>
      @endcan
    </td>
    @endcanany
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Cloud Soh Hun Fu. This answer helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gate Facade like this:

```
@if(Gate::check('update-post') || Gate::check('update-post2'))

@endif
```

And you can define your permissions in App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider liek this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('update-post', function ($user, $post) {
        return $user->id == $post->user_id;
    });
}
```

OR

```
@if($user->can('perm1') || $user->can('perm2'))
    // do something
@endif
```

Comment: I know this will work and I have tried them. My question was, how to check two auth Gates by the "can" method in the view file ?